# rpy2: prevent StrVector from factorisation when put into a DataFrame

Tags: python, r, rpy2

In `rpy2`, I noticed that a `StrVector` is factorised once it's put into a `DataFrame`. An example is the following.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

series_1 = ("0", "0", "0", "0")
series_1_robject = ro.StrVector(series_1)  # => ['0', '0', '0', '0']
df = ro.DataFrame({"series_1": series_1_robject})    # => FactorVector [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And...

```
>>> df[0][1]
1
```

It appears that when I build a `DataFrame`, my nice `StrVector` gets factorised, so `0` corresponds to factor value `1` (being R is 1-indexed), and so on. But how would I stop this from happening? It's pretty essential for me that when the input vector (`series_1`) is `0,0,0...,0`, its representation in the resulting `DataFrame` will be `0`, not `1`. So far, I have not really been able to find anything on this matter in the documentation....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the note [here](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html#dataframe), you can prevent this conversion to `FactorVector` by wrapping the `StrVector` with a call to [`ro.r.I()` (the "as-is" function in R)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/AsIs.html):

```
In [1]: import rpy2.robjects as ro

In [2]: series_1 = ("0", "0", "0", "0")

In [3]: series_1_robject = ro.StrVector(series_1)

In [4]: df = ro.DataFrame({"series_1": series_1_robject})

In [5]: df.rx2("series_1")
Out[5]:
R object with classes: ('factor',) mapped to:
<FactorVector - Python:0x113a39368 / R:0x7f8d15882e40>
[       1,        1,        1,        1]

In [6]: df = ro.DataFrame({"series_1": ro.r.I(series_1_robject)})

In [7]: df.rx2("series_1")
Out[7]:
R object with classes: ('AsIs',) mapped to:
<StrVector - Python:0x113a398c0 / R:0x7f8d13a8aec8>
[str, str, str, str]
```